# Unclosed Connector Error "connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7ff29a063eb0>"

Tags: python, discord

The code below gives me a connection error. The code is:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import shelve

client = discord.Client()

food = ""
products = ["Jam", "Jacket-Potato", "Salmon", "Egg", "Jelly"]
keys = shelve.open('keys')
token = keys["Profitable_Pinger"] 

def products_start_with_j():
    global food
    for product in products:
        if product.startswith('J'):
            food = product
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            loop.run_until_complete(client.start(token))
            print(f'{food} has been sent on discord')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    chan = client.get_channel(Channel Number)
    await chan.send(food)
    await client.close()


products_start_with_j()
```

The error I get is:

```
Jam has been sent on discord
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f9de780b5b0>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7f9de76acee0>, 4.273178344)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7f9de7832fd0>
Jacket-Potato has been sent on discord
Jelly has been sent on discord
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f9de768cf40>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7f9de76acee0>, 4.453377141)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7f9de780b250>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I get the above error and on my discord channel, it only sends 'Jam' even though it claims it has sent 'Jacket Potato' and 'Jelly'.

Comment: p.s I also tried it without the time.sleep but same thing.

Comment: Please add an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a stack trace, not only the error msg.

Comment: always put full error message (staring at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenho). There areother usful information.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestions on how to post understandable questions. I have edited the entire post to a Minimal, Reproducible example  showing the full error. @furas.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestions on how to post understandable questions. I have edited the entire post to a Minimal, Reproducible example  showing the full error. @sophros

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do. Why do you use `for`-loop with `asyncio` ? Why don't you use`for`-loop directly in `on_ready` without asyncio?

Comment: Obviously the script above is a simplified unrelated script but  what I am asking and trying to demonstrate through it applies to the the actual script. For some reason I just never thought of running the for loop in the on_ready, not sure why I didn't think of that.  I have just tried that and it works perfectly. Im still new to python but I guess for some reason that I was trying to overcomplicate things. Thank you @furas.

Comment: @Temi9568 - can you please paste the solution?